# Add "delete row and shift up" function to script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that takes B2 cell as input from google sheets. I set up a list of strings I want to process in rows. I want to "delete cell and shift up" in B2 cell after I run the script. To create a kind of magazine of strings to be input.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your code (change "spreadsheet" with the variable you're using for selecting the sheet):

```
spreadsheet.getRange('B2').deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Sheet.deleteRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition) or [Range.deleteCells()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#deletecellsshiftdimension), but it would probably make more sense to iterate through the values in column `B2:B` with something like this:

```js
function magazine() {
  const strings = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet1!B2:B').getValues().flat();
  strings.forEach(string => myFunctionThatUsesStringInB2(string));
}
```